# Setting and Getting String Values from an ArrayList<Object>

Tags: java

Created get and set methods for object Verb. Would like to create 6 Verb Objects, place them into an Array List. Then populate a spinner with the maori String for each of the objects.

```
public class Verb {
String maori;
String english;

public void setEnglish(String myText){
    english = myText;
}
public String getEnglish(){
    return english;
}
public void setMaori(String myText){
    maori = myText;
}
public String getMaori(){
    return maori;
}
}
```

From MainActivity.

Oncreate()

```
Verb patu = new Verb();
patu.setMaori=("patu");
patu.setEnglish="hit");
verbArrayList.add(patu);
```

then later on if i want to retreive that value

```
String retrivedMaori = veryArrayList.get(patu.getMaori());
```

Ok so ULTIMATELY the Verb Class will have a lot more fields. E.g

```
    haere = new Verb();
    haere.setMaori("haere");
    haere.setiTAM("went");
    haere.setKua(("gone"));
    haere.setKeite("going");
    haere.setEana("going");
    haere.setKa("go");
    haere.setMe("go");
    verbArrayList.add(haere);
```

Is HashMap still the best one to store this Verb Object? It will have multiple variables and I just want to populate the spinner with the maori version.

Comment: `veryArrayList.get(index).getMaori()` is the correct way to use `List`. Maybe you should try with `HashMap` instead.

Comment: What is your goal? Do you want to be able to retrieve a Maori verb using the english for it and vice-versa? If this is so, you can use 2 `HashMap<String, Verb>` instead of a List here.

Comment: Is Hashmap still the best way to go if theres far more then two variables? So far theres 8 different String variables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isolate this:

```
String retrievedMaori = veryArrayList.get(patu.getMaori());
```

Apart from it being incorrect, if you already have `patu`, then you don't even need the list:

```
String retrievedMaori = patu.getMaori();
```

But I doubt that you'll have the `Verb patu` object at that point. You'll merely have the index of the element. If so, you can do this to retrieve the `Verb` object, then the maori:

```
Verb v = veryArrayList.get(index);
String retrievedMaori = v.getMaori();
```

---

If you later want to be able to retrieve a verb from any language, you probably want maps instead:

```
HashMap<String,Verb> maoriToVerb = new HashMap<>();
HashMap<String,Verb> englishToVerb = new HashMap<>();

// create a verb
Verb patu = new Verb();
patu.setMaori("patu");
patu.setEnglish("hit");

// add it to both dictionaries
maoriToVerb.put(patu.getMaori(), patu);
englishToVerb.put(patu.getEnglish(), patu);

// how to get english from maori
String knownMaori = "patu";
Verb retrievedVerbFromMaori = maoriToVerb.get(knownMaori);
String retrievedEnglish = retrievedVerbFromMaori.getEnglish();

// how to get maori from english
String knownEnglish = "hit";
Verb retrievedVerbFromEnglish = englishToVerb.get(knownEnglish);
String retrievedMaori = retrievedVerbFromEnglish.getMaori();
```

To populate your spinner, you can get the keys of the maori map this way:

```
Set<String> maoriStrings = maoriToVerb.keySet();
```

Comment: I am still wondering if this is the best way to go if I have more then just these two values? I need to encorperate all the other tense version of the word hit. e.g "hitting.

Comment: As long as all values are different (no 2 different english words have the same maori translation), this will be no problem.

Answer (score 0):

`veryArrayList.get(patu.getMaori())` is wrong.

`veryArrayList.get(index)` is itself a instance of 'patu'.

`veryArrayList.get(index).getMaori();` is correct.

Comment: thank you, yeah that code was a bit spray and pray to be hoest lol

Answer (score 0):

in place of

```
patu.setMaori=("patu");
patu.setEnglish="hit");
verbArrayList.add(patu);
```

write

```
patu.setMaori("patu");
patu.setEnglish("hit");
verbArrayList.add(patu);
```

and in place of

```
String retrivedMaori = veryArrayList.get(patu.getMaori());
```

write

```
String retrivedMaori = veryArrayList.get(0).getMaori();
```